# Connecting and updating php server from Android application

Tags: php, android, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have created a gps application which works fine. Now what i am trying is to connect it to a php server with mysql database where all the locations of the people are updated automatically.. I am a **new user** for this part. I have tried some of it but I dont think its write.. Can someone help me and guide me to the process about how should i do it.. Your help will be really appreciated. Below is the code i wrote from a frieds help and the php script.

```
public class Post extends LocService {{


TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String deviceid = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();



    //this is JSON part to put your information inside it
    String postData = "{\"request\":{\"type\":\"locationinfo\"},\"userinfo\":{\"latitude\":\""+latitude+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude+"\",\"deviceid\":\""+deviceid+"\"}}";


    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    // Post method to send data to server
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://location.net/storeg.php");


    SQLiteDatabase db = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {

        if(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Sync")).equals("yes") ) {

            String mob = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("MobileID"));
            String latitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Latitude"));
            String longitude = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Longitude"));
            String service = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Service"));


            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            try {
                json.put("MobileID", mob);
                json.put("Latitude", latitude);
                json.put("Longitude", longitude);
                json.put("Service", service);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                receive = HttpPostExample.SendJsonUpdate(json, Sync_URL);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Toast.makeText(context,  receive,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();    
    }
    cursor.close();













    try {
        post.setURI(new URI("http://location.net/storeg.php"));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // set your post data inside post method    
    try {
        post.setEntity(new StringEntity(postData));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // execute post request here 
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}
}
```

PHP Script

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
 {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("mel_db", $con);

$latitude = $_POST['latitude'];
$longitude = $_POST['longitude'];
$service = $_POST['service'];
$devid = $_POST['devid'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO  `mehul_db`.`locations` (
`id` ,
`devid` ,
`latitude` ,
`longitude` ,
`service`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  '$devid',  '$latitude',  '$longitude',  '$service'
);";
if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Please help me with the process... Or suggest me about how should i do it..

**EDITED:**Got this code can i use it for getting the latitude and longitude after changing the variables..?

```
String result;
    try{


            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);


            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){


                    JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);


                    Log.i("log_tag","id: "+json_data.getInt("id")+


                            ", name: "+json_data.getString("name")+


                            ", sex: "+json_data.getInt("sex")+


                            ", birthyear: "+json_data.getInt("birthyear")


                   );


            }


   finally }


    }catch(JSONException e){


            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());


    }


}
```

Comment: What problems do you face? Do you encounter any errors?

Comment: actuall i just wrote the code.. is the writing part correct..? could you suggest me how do i do it..

Comment: `receive = HttpPostExample.SendJsonUpdate(json, Sync_URL);`

Comment: error on the above line and these two lines and `SQLiteDatabase db = databasehelper.getWritableDatabase();`
        `Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE, null, null, null, null);`

Comment: It would be difficult for us to go through the entire code and verify it. Why don't you run it and see if it works and if it doesn't, come back with the problems that you face.

Comment: ohk.. is there any other way to do what i asked..?

Comment: Can you please update your original post? Please post the LogCat output also.

Comment: I got the above 3 errors.. how can i run it..?

Answer (score 0):

```
     String url="http://location.net/storeg.php";

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", latitude));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", longitude));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("service", service));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("devid", devid));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
```

you can use this code to send parametrs to php through post and in response you will get inputstream.

Comment: Thankx Ankita.. will just try it out.. One more thing do i need to write anything in json..?

Comment: no you don't need to write anything in json. after getting value of lattitude and longitude from database just send it with key as done in code.

Comment: nameValuePairs list is key value pair.here  left value is key and with same key retrieve value in php.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again..Where do i put the code...? between what..?